# Arcgis featureset to kml client side

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml, csv

I want to convert a js feature set retrieved from a geoprocessing service to a kml client side, and perhaps also to a csv (i have the object from the JS API).

Is there any way do this?

To clarify:
i work on the client side and were using google earth (even though it's deprecated, i know), the client consumes a geoprocessing service, it could consume the service via rest but that's non preferable because i wan't to have it as the result as an object, so i want to use the ArcGIS JS API to consume the service and load it to google earth as a kml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on the question. If you are creating the feature class thorough an API, you can [add a KML feature to ArcGIS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_kml.html).  If you are receiving a feature from the API, you can convert that to KML using the conversion tool in ArcMap. [Here are a few tips for that.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s200000009000000)

Comment: i have edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: I would look around on the ArcGIS Developers site. I referenced it above, there is quite a bit of information out there about working between ESRI products and Google Earth. Here is another link as well:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/kmllayer.html